# Firebase realtime not working correctly on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, frontend

I'm creating lobby for game and I want to display player list. I'm watching for new players in room.

```
const [roomUsers, setRoomUsers] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    if (room)
        DB.collection("room_users").where("room_id", "==", room.id)
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                const newRoomUsers = [];

                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    newRoomUsers.push(doc.data());
                });

                setRoomUsers(newRoomUsers)
            });
})
```

When I join in the second window, the number of players changes but the list updates over time. When I join more times, the list stops updating at all.

```
<h4>Players list ({roomUsers.length}/4)</h4>

{roomUsers.map(roomUser => (
   <PlayerListItem
      roomUser={roomUser}
      owner={roomUser.uuid === room.owner}
   />
 ))}
```

In PlayerListItem component I am fetching the user via uuid

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    DB.collection('users').where('uuid', '==', roomUser.uuid).get().then(snapshot => {
        if (!snapshot.empty)
            setUser(snapshot.docs[0].data())
    })
}, [])
```

Then I return the username through the component.

Sometimes the same username appears twice in the list instead of different

Comment: Do you have the room variable as a dependency on your first useEffect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect is missing the dependencies array. It should also return the cleanup function

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!room) {
        return;
    }

    const unsub = DB.collection("room_users").where("room_id", "==", room.id)
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const newRoomUsers = [];
             querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                newRoomUsers.push(doc.data());
            });

            setRoomUsers((currVal) => {
                console.log({currVal, newRoomUsers})

                const newVal = [] // change this to be correct

                return newVal
            })
    });

    return () => unsub();

}, [room])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but now the roomUsers array doesn't always update correctly, when a user leaves a room, the wrong one disappears from the list. As if React was just looking at the index number.

Comment: Ok, I changed the setRoomUsers to the callback syntax (which means that react will now provide us with the currVal). My hope is that the console log will give you some clues about how you can go about preparing newVal